# How do I make a seekbar whose initail progress which is zero, starts in the middle

Tags: android, custom-controls, android-seekbar

I want to customize the SeekBar as shown below in the image.[image: Make a seekbar like this one]

I'm a beginner in programming and I looked for tutorials, but every where the progress starts in the leftmost corner. Can someone please guide me how can I customize the SeekBar.

So In onProgresschanged.

```
 @Override
 public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,int progress, boolean fromUser) {            
brightness = progress;
    putGestureImageOnScreen(doBrightness(imageBitmap, brightness));
 }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seekbars in Android cannot have negative values. Assuming you have specified a value of '100' for your maximum range of the progress bar (for example using setMax(100) or in your xml file using android:max="100"), then you can use this method to move your progress bar to the middle whenever you want (for example in your Activity.onCreate() or wherever else)

```
    yourProgressBar.setProgress(50);
```

After that you can get the progress value using:

```
    int progress = yourProgressBar.getProgress();
```

If you want to have a progress value between (e.g.) -50 to +50, then you can simply use:

```
    int progress = yourProgressBar.getProgress();
    progress -= 50;
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, for the explanation. So how do manage the progress variable with increasing and decreasing its value?

Comment: The above code mentioned for onProgressChanged(), is that enough?

Comment: yes, you can get notified of new progress values in onProgressChanged().

Comment: and ALWAYS, if you feel an answer has helped you, use the 'tick' sign on your left to 'accept' that answer. This way you have both helped other people learn something new, and thanked the answerer :-)

Comment: Is there any way to display progress in both directions ? I mean, If I move thumb in either direction then progress should start from centre to position of thumb moved. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK `SeekBar` with negative value is not possible in `Android`.
For this take Your `SeekBar` bar range from 0 to 100.
You can set it like..

```
seekbar.setMax(100);
```

initially start from the center like..

```
seekbar.setProgress(50);
```

And decrese it from the 50 to 0

Answer (score 0):

Through xml you can do it as : `android:progress="20"` means 20 is default position. Starting point of seek bar.

Or in your code you can do it like:

```
your_seekBar.setProgress(start_position);
```

ie. `your_seekBar.setProgress(20)`

you can adjust as you want

Answer (score 0):

place this in Oncreate

```
 seekBar=((SeekBar)(v.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1)));
    seekBar.setMax(100);
    seekBar.setProgress(50);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a blog about custom seekbar.You can look [this](http://dilipdevelopment.blogspot.in/2013/04/custom-android-seekbar-developement.html).As Kalyan Said you need to set `Max` and `progress` of the `seekBar`.

```
seekbar.setMax(100);
seekbar.setProgress(50);//Set default progress of the Seekbar
```