# How to set the ''CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION'' in Camera2 API on Android?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, autoexposurecompensation

I'm currently working on Androids Camera 2 API and my current problem is, that I cannot set the "CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION".

My code:

> -1.0 < exposureAdjustment <1.0

```
public void setExposure(double exposureAdjustment) {
    Range<Integer> range1 = mCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_COMPENSATION_RANGE);
    int minExposure = range1.getLower();
    int maxExposure = range1.getUpper();

    float newCalculatedValue = 0;
    if (exposureAdjustment >= 0) {
        newCalculatedValue = (float) (minExposure * exposureAdjustment);
    } else {
        newCalculatedValue = (float) (maxExposure * -1 * exposureAdjustment);
    }

    mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION, (int) newCalculatedValue);
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution, which works for me. Whereby the `exposureAdjustment` parameter is between -1 to +1.

```
public void setExposure(double exposureAdjustment) {
    Range<Integer> range1 = mCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_COMPENSATION_RANGE);

    int minExposure = range1.getLower();
    int maxExposure = range1.getUpper();

    if (minExposure != 0 || maxExposure != 0) {
        float newCalculatedValue = 0;
        if (exposureAdjustment >= 0) {
            newCalculatedValue = (float) (minExposure * exposureAdjustment);
        } else {
            newCalculatedValue = (float) (maxExposure * -1 * exposureAdjustment);
        }

        if (mPreviewRequestBuilder != null) {
            try {
                CaptureRequest captureRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();
                mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequest, camera2FocusMeteringManager.mCaptureCallbackListener, mBackgroundHandler);
                mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION, (int) newCalculatedValue);
                mCaptureSession.capture(captureRequest, camera2FocusMeteringManager.mCaptureCallbackListener, mBackgroundHandler);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where I build a new `CaptureRequest` via my `mPreviewRequestBuilder` (A builder for capture requests) for each exposure adjustment.

[Here](https://github.com/ManuelSchmitzberger/Camera2) you can find a full Camera2 example.

Comment: Your _newCalculatedValue_ is going to -367 to something everytime. It's not between  _-1 to 1_

Comment: @PiyushGupta that could be possible. The `newCaluclatedValue` is not between -1 to 1. The method input parameter is between -1 to 1. I've updated the answer a little bit. Additionally you can find a link to a full camera2 example. Hope that helps.

Comment: If your code works proper then can you please share that part of code or java class file of it?  @Manuel Schmitzberger.   I will be thankful to you for it

Comment: To set the max exposure, which is supported by the device you need to call: `setExposure(-1)` respectively `setExposure(1)`.

Comment: Okay you mean for seek bar can i set max progress to 1 if  i need value between _-1 to 1_

Comment: Were you updating your exposure value on seekbar progress ?? @Manuel Schmitzberger

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22034584/4291264) you can find, how to set the seekbar between -1 to 1 (replace 50) and for the update you can use the `onProgressChanged` in the `OnSeekBarChangeListener` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11639163/4291264) you can find an example.

Comment: I have added question. Can you please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53514188/change-control-ae-exposure-compensation-propostional-to-seekbar-progress-in-came)