# Change CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION propostional to seekbar progress in Camera2 API

Tags: android, seekbar, android-camera2

I'm currently working on Androids Camera 2 API and my current problem is, that I cannot set the `CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION`.

I want to exposure between  *-2 to 2*.

Here is my code.

```
public void setExposure(double exposureAdjustment) {
    Range<Integer> range1 = mCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_COMPENSATION_RANGE);
    int minExposure = range1.getLower();
    int maxExposure = range1.getUpper();

    float newCalculatedValue = 0;
    if (exposureAdjustment >= 0) {
        newCalculatedValue = (float) (minExposure * exposureAdjustment);
    } else {
        newCalculatedValue = (float) (maxExposure * -1 * exposureAdjustment);
    }

    try {
        CaptureRequest captureRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();
        mPreviewSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest,
                mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(captureRequest.CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION, (int) newCalculatedValue);
        mPreviewSession.capture(captureRequest, mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);

        Log.v("cascascasc", exposureAdjustment + " : " + newCalculatedValue);

    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

On Seekbar change listener i call

```
    exposure_seekbar.setMin(-2);
    exposure_seekbar.setMax(2);
    exposure_seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {

            if (b) {
                mCamera2Fragment.setExposure((double)i);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: is there any exception which you can share? or other additional input?

Comment: No there is not any exception. But i am not able to visually check the exposure effect.

Comment: @ManuelSchmitzberger Can you please share your Java class file if your code working properly?

Comment: This [previeFragement](https://github.com/ManuelSchmitzberger/Camera2/blob/master/camera2/src/main/java/us/yydcdut/camera2/ui/PreviewFragment.java#L171) should work. So you only need to add your `setExposure(...)` and seekbar method.

Comment: Should I replace my _cameraFragment_ class with your _PreviewFragment_? If then will your code support aspect ratio for camera preview for all devices ??

Comment: I don't know, how your project looks like.
>If then will your code support aspect ratio for camera preview for all devices ??<
should be, yes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52520356/549372

Comment: @MartinZeitler Is it the same as Exposure? As i know it just increase brightness in the link